# How to export 'ls' command in bash to separate variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

For example:

```
List="$(ls ~/Downloads)" 
echo $List
```

Output will be:

```
ExampleDirectory Example_Directory ExampleFile
```

How do I get (after `ls`):

```
echo $File1
echo $File2 
echo $File3
```

To get

```
ExampleDirectory
Example_Directory
ExampleFile
```

Like separate ls output to make not just line of text like in `$List`, but variables `$File1`, `$File2` and `$File3`.
It seems a bit complicated.

Comment: In general, `ls` output is not good for parsing. It is made for human read and can change its format depending on were it is written to. Are you trying to have an array with the names of files in the directory as its elements? Tell us what you want  to achieve and you may get better help.

Comment: I need to launch programs listed in few folders via dmenu.

Comment: Why do you want the names in different variables?  Probably you can do what you need with a simple loop: `for f in $HOME/Downloads/*; do ...; done`

Comment: @Xiaomi Account - How do you intend to use those _separate variables_ with `dmenu`?

Comment: @Armali I want to make list with programs and run them by choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign each file (or directory name) in `~/Downloads` to a different `bash` variable, you will have to find different names for these variables. It would be simpler to use a `bash` indexed array:

```
$ declare -a List=(~/Downloads/*)
```

Then, to print them all:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${List[@]}"
```

To print only the first and third one:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${List[0]}" "${List[2]}"
```

To print the number of entries in the `List` array:

```
$ printf '%d\n' "${#List[@]}"
```